# How to update a div's style background-color to none using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My brain is going crazy on figuring out how to modify the `background color` within a `div` that has a `class`, with an inline style controlling the color of the div.

I'd like to know how I would be able to change the background color from within one div but leave the other div's background color intact. As you can see, the div's contain the same class names, but the inline style color is what I'm trying to update. I'm also unable to modify the structure of the html page, otherwise, this would be a piece of cake.

With a css class I can write something like this to look at the current `class` and replace it with another `class` but In this situation this isn't an option since this syntax would change all the divs with the similar divs.

```
$('.tx-cal-event').toggleClass({"sx-abc-event"});


<div class="nx-cal-event nx-cal-event-month" style="background-color: rgb(182, 232, 198);"></div>
<div class="nx-cal-event nx-cal-event-month" style="background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);"></div>
<div class="nx-cal-event nx-cal-event-month" style="background-color: rgb(166, 166, 166);"></div>
```

I imagine to somehow identify the one color in a div and make it transparent via a button. I have the button variable but its the actual syntax for changing the color when it is referenced in an inline style element.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using the css() method in jQuery and check if it works http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @CharanrajGolla I can almost see it in this sytanx from the link you provided. 

<script>
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  var color = $( this ).css( "background-color" );
  $( "#result" ).html( "That div is <span style='color:" +
    color + ";'>" + color + "</span>." );
});
</script> 

But it would need to grab the div and style and replace it with another css statement. 

If <div class="nx-cal-event nx-cal-event-month" style="background-color: rgb(182, 232, 198);"></div> then replace with new color syntax here?

Comment: Can you help in understanding what event/ element in UI triggers this action? Also it would be helpful if you show more code. With the limited amount of code available in the question it is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @CharanrajGolla check out the codepen I created: 
    https://codepen.io/nickfs000/pen/BYKEgr

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://codepen.io/charanrajgolla/pen/MQeYmB nth-child pseudo selector would help you select elements. More info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child

Comment: Yes that is it! Oh man, thank you! I better get to learning pseudo selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code pen snippet I modified the selector to use the pseudo selector. This snippet hides the other two divs and retains the styling for the 1st one.

Code Pen link :https://codepen.io/charanrajgolla/pen/MQeYmB
More information about n-th Child can be found over here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child

Code Sample :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
$(this).parents('.dimensions').find('p:nth-child(2n+1), p:last-child').fadeToggle(700);
  });
});
```

```css
/* This is the css in question */

.tx-cal-event {
 color: black;
 font-family: "ABeeZee";
}

.sx-abc-event {
 font-size:100%;
 background-color: #CCC!important;
 border-radius: 2px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.nx-cal-event-month {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/* this css is for formatting of the elements and not important in finding what is being asked for */
body {
 background-color: #000;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: black;
}
.dimensions { 
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;}

.btn-css {
  background: rgb(0,112,210);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dimensions">
  <button class="btn-css">Click Button</button>
    <p class="tx-cal-event nx-cal-event-month" style="background-color: rgb(182, 232, 198);">
If I click the button, 1 and 2 should be hidden, but this row should remain visible, alongwith keeping the background-color value of <br>rgb(182, 232, 198).</p>
    <p class="tx-cal-event nx-cal-event-month" style="background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);">1. This Should Dissappear</p>
    <p class="tx-cal-event nx-cal-event-month" style="background-color: rgb(166, 166, 166);">2. This Should Dissappear</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try
 `$('#tx-cal-event').css({'background-color':'transparent'});`

Answer (score 0):

Try below jquery:

```
$('.tx-cal-event').css('background-color', 'transparent !important');
```

Or define this css in you class like below

```
<style>
 .bg-none{
    $background-color: transparent !important;
  }
</style>

// Then in your javascript
<script>
 $('.tx-cal-event').addClass('bg-none');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `background-color` to **initial** using `css()` jQuery. No need to use `!important`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$("div.nx-cal-event.nx-cal-event-month").css({
  "background-color": "initial"
});
```

```css
.nx-cal-event.nx-cal-event-month {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nx-cal-event nx-cal-event-month" style="background-color: rgb(222, 174, 234);"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the inline style property use [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method with an empty string as second parameter:

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g. $( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "" ) — removes that property from an element if it has already been directly applied, whether in the HTML style attribute, through jQuery's .css() method, or through direct DOM manipulation of the style property. As a consequence, the element's style for that property will be restored to whatever value was applied.

Usage

```
$('.tx-cal-event').css('background-color', '');
```